# axios delete request doesn't delete element from array ($pull) even after status:200

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

posting for the first time.I am trying to $pull an id from array in my mongodb database.  I tried it in postman and it works perfectly fine but when it comes to using it in my react app, it wont.  This the axios code

```
 const unassignAgent = async() => {

        console.log(id, agentId)
        try{
            
             
            const data = await axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/customerRequestByAdmin/unassign/${id}`,{
                // assignedTo,
                status:"New lead"
                // agentId,
            },config);

            const agent = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/customerRequestByAdmin/agentunassigned/${agentId}`,{
               id: id,
            },{
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  withCredentials:true
                })
            // window.location.reload(false);    
            console.log(data);
            console.log(agent);
            
            // console.log(assignedTo)
        }
        catch(error){
            // window.alert("there was an error unassigning request. contact the developer")
        }
        
       
    }
```

this is the express code of it.

```
exports.removeCustomersToAgentArray = async(req,res,next) =>{
    let agentId = req.params.id
    try{
        const response = await Agent.findByIdAndUpdate(agentId,{
            $pull:{assignedRequest:req.body.id}
        })        
        res.send(response)
        
    }
    catch(err){
        
    }
}
```

this is the data structure

```
age: 35
assignedRequest: (2) ['6190f014da672bb9e62e5e5d', '6190f15ff22e36d3747a9ade']
emailId: "ek@gmail.com"
firstName: "ekta"
gender: "female"
lastName: "kapoor"
password: "$2b$10$pDEkwJiOMiR7Vyfb6w1S5umavWIKpq"
```

[image: Server Console log]

Comment: console log `req.body.id` and check if you are getting correct ID from frontend.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little. Its undefined but if you checkout the image I have added, the data being sent undefined but there is new key value pair of id that is created, where the correct id goes. why is that happening?

Comment: The key/value pair is under `headers` not under `body`, so your code should be `req.headers.id` instead of `req.body.id`

Comment: maybe I am getting you wrong but as I can see its inside config and not headers. how do I make it into body? I have added my code if you can help me with that.

Comment: I have shared it already, what else will you need?

Comment: Okay, I found the answer @ShivamSood. axios.delete doesn't automatically assume the second object parameter as the data to be sent to server as req.body instead we have to send like this: `const response = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/yourRouteFromServer`,{data:{key: value}},{headers: {Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8','Content-Type': 'application/json',},withCredentials:true})`

Comment: or we can send all data through params

Comment: Thankyou for directing me into the right direction @ShivamSood .

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer @ShivamSood. axios.delete doesn't automatically assume the second object parameter as the data to be sent to server as req.body as other axios functions do, instead we have to send like this:

```
 const response = await axios.delete(localhost:3000/yourRouteFromServer,{data:{key: value}},{headers: {Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8','Content-Type': 'application/json',},withCredentials:true})
```

or we can send all data through params.